# Динамическое создание условий поведения классов

Tags: c#

В программе есть заранее заготовленные классы, описывающие насос, задвижку, датчик давления. Насос получает от пользователя команды и меняет состояния включен \ отключен. Задвижка получает команды и меняет состояния открыта \ закрыта. Датчик давления просто отображает пользователю некое значение, которое просчитывает программа. Экземпляры всех этих объектов пользователь создает сам.

Прошу помощи в определении принципа динамического формирования условий поведения экземпляров этих классов. Для примера - пользователь создает экземпляр насоса и датчика давления на выходе насоса, затем через интерфейс определяет условие - "Если насос включен, то давление на выходе = 10, если насос выключен, то давление на выходе = 0". Далее пользователь может создать задвижку между датчиком давления и насосом. При этом можно добавить условие - если задвижка закрыта, то давление всегда = 0. Возможно дальнейшее наращивание схемы - несколько насосов, подключенных параллельно, давление должно вырасти при работе хотя бы одного из них. Не могу пока понять как в принципе эти условия динамически формировать и хранить.

Добавлено:

Вообще описанная проблема относится к написанию программного симулятора насосной перекачивающей станции. Симулятор связан с ПЛК, который осуществляет управление моделью. В случае с насосами и давлением на выходе сейчас сделано просто - в классе насоса есть ссылка на экземпляр датчика давления, значение меняется прямо из класса насоса. Но в случае когда у нас стоят 2 насоса параллельно и есть 1 датчик, то будет конфликт.

В целом в модели показывать переходные процессы нужно, но не нужно делать это точно. Вполне хватит линейных изменений сигналов до величин, определенных пользователем и за время, определенное им же.

Comment: WinForms. Но вопрос касается именно "привязки" некого поля из класса датчика давления. Ну или формирования значения поля в зависимости от условий, определенных пользователем.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но вопрос все же в реализации самой модели поведения класса

Comment: Довольно абстрактно описано. Как планируется использовать? Будут готовые блоки где визуально можно настроить условия или всё таки это будет настройка кодом? Комбинация условий - это уже программный код или наоборот настройка пользователем в UI?

Comment: Вам нужно учитывать переходные процессы или считаем что состояние равновесия устанавливается мгновенно? Я такое уже делал, поэтому если не сложно добавьте в вопрос какие особенности физической модели конкретно нужно реализовать. Там много нюансов от которых зависит возможная реализация. Общую схему набросаю, но без подробностей это сферический конь в вакууме.

Comment: @Monk Условия формирует пользователь через UI.

Comment: @rdorn Вопрос дополнил, но ваш ответ на мысли уже натолкнул, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите, в первом приближении вам нужно определить терминальные элементы (насос, камера в которой получаем давление или что там у вас) и промежуточные (задвижка, труба, датчик давления).

У терминальных элементов есть только одно соединение - это либо вход, либо выход в зависимости от направления потока перекачиваемого вещества. Если насос увеличивает давление - значит для него это выход, если уменьшает - вход. Аналогично для всех остальных.

У промежуточных - минимум один вход и один выход.

Теперь нам нужно соединить входы с выходами, сделать можно массой различных способов, в простейшем случае - обычный связный список в котором выход одного элемента указывает на вход другого.

Для каждого входа и выхода определяем параметр, фиксирующий давление в сечении этого входа или выхода. У соединенных входа и выхода эти параметры должны быть равны. Например, включили насос, давление на его входе/выходе изменилось, меняем давление на выходе/входе присоединенного элемента, передать это изменение дальше, уже задача этого присоединенного элемента. Это тоже можно сделать массой способов, можно использовать стандартное решение с `INotifyPropertyChanged`, или что-то самодельное, опять же зависит от физической модели.

---

С учетом подробностей моделируемого процесса, проще всего будет сделать таймер с постоянным интервалом (интервал подбирается в процессе, начать можно с 0,1 сек.) На события таймера подписываются все элементы моделируемой схемы подключения. По событию производится пересчет передачи давления за интервал времени со входов на выходы элемента, а также обработка действий введенных пользователем.

---

> Для примера - пользователь создает экземпляр насоса и датчика давления на выходе насоса, затем через интерфейс определяет условие - "Если насос включен, то давление на выходе = 10, если насос выключен, то давление на выходе = 0".

Этот момент лучше, для пользователя, реализовать как-то так:

- Пользователь создает насос, например путем выбора из реально существующих моделей и импорта параметров насоса из БД или файла, либо задает параметры вручную через диалог.
- Пользователь создает все необходимые элементы трубопровода, задвижки, диафрагмы, датчики, разветвители и т.д. и т.п. аналогично выбирая из реальных прототипов, либо настраивая параметры в ручную.
- Пользователь соединяет элементы в нужной последовательности. На этом этапе можно и нужно реализовать проверки, что пользователь не пытается соединить трубы разных диаметров или, проще говоря, проверяется совместимость выбранных компонентов трубопровода.
- Пользователь завершает редактирование схемы и включает режим моделирования процесса. Начиная с этого момента, пользователь не может менять параметры и компоненты схемы, а может только отдавать команды активным элементам, таким как насосы и задвижки, а также в реальном времени (все элементы пересчитываются по тику таймера) наблюдать за параметрами установленных датчиков.

Также стоит предусмотреть сигнализацию об авариях, если не смотря на совместимость элементов, где-то что-то пошло не так из-за логической ошибки  в конфигурации схемы, например не выключили насос и давление в трубе превысило максимально допустимое, в реальных условиях это кончается разрушением элемента, о чем модель должна сообщить.

PS: У меня была задача моделирования вакуумных систем, но большая часть программных проблем весьма сходная, так что если нужно, обращайтесь, забыл еще не все. Единственное с чем не помогу - интерфейс редактора схемы трубопровода, так и не осилил его в свое время.